# Cannot read property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined meteor production

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, production

When I put my meteor app in production, I get these error messages:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'easing' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined
```

These are my installed packages:

accounts-password
alanning:roles
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:delete-button
aldeed:moment-timezone
aldeed:simple-schema
alethes:pages
bevanhunt:leaflet
blaze-html-templates
dapearce:material-icons
dburles:collection-helpers
ecmascript
email
es5-shim
force-ssl
gildaspk:autoform-materialize 
iron:router
jquery
matb33:collection-hooks
materialize:materialize
meteor-base
mizzao:user-status
mobile-experience
momentjs:moment
mongo
pcel:loading
pfafman:filesaver
reactive-var
service-configuration
session
standard-minifier-css
standard-minifier-js
tracker
useraccounts:core
useraccounts:iron-routing
useraccounts:materialize

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are using service configuration for third party login/signup like the code given below:

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
  { service: "weibo" },
  { $set: { clientId: "1292962797", secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc" } }
);

Comment: I'm getting this too, with similar packages, on 1.4.0.1

Comment: @see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3506 to track this issue (no answer yet)